# any way to route IP to IP traffix in linux

Tags: networking

source server  has two IPs

192.168.100.1

192.168.100.2

And CS has

192.168.200.1

192.168.200.2

Route like this based on destination.

192.168.200.1 -> 192.168.100.1

192.168.200.2 -> 192.168.100.2

Comment: Sounds like homework. We don't do other people's homework here. Check your course notes, and read `man ip ip-route`.

Comment: when's your homework due?